# Selectbox after select it will back to default

Tags: php

```
?>
<?php

$get1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY categoryid 
ASC");
$option1 = '';
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($get1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$option1 .= '<option value = "' . $row1['categoryname'] . '">' . 
$row1['categoryname'] . '</option>'; 
}
if (isset($_POST['categoryname'])) {

$get3 = mysqli_query($conn, "select subcategoryname from subcategory where 
categoryid = (select categoryid from category where categoryname 
='$_POST[categoryname]' )");
$option3 = '';
while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($get3, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$option3 .= '<option value = "' . $row3['subcategoryname'] . '">' . 
$row3['subcategoryname'] . '</option>'; 
}
 }
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo 
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
<label style="margin-left:6px;margin-bottom: 30px; ">Category:</label>
<select  onchange='this.form.submit()' selected name = "categoryname" 
 style="margin-left: 70px;width: 200px"> 
                        <?php echo $option1; ?>
                    </select><noscript><input type="" ></noscript> <br> <br>
                    <label style="margin-left:6px;margin-bottom: 30px; ">Sub 
Category:</label><select name = "subcategoryname" style="margin-left: 
70px;width: 200px"> 
                        <?php echo $option3; ?>
                    </select> <br> <br> 

</form>
```

Ma'am and sir i need help. I'll ask on how i will generate my subcategory selectbox after i select category without coming back to its default or first ,because if i click any  in category yes, it will generate data on subcategorybox but after that it will affect category it will back to its default value.so What i want it will still hold what i selected category and will still generate subcategory, I hope someone can help me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe Javascript / jQuery needs to be used to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why you not try with jquery and ajax sir ? you want to triggering category, right ? you just need to give onchange in your option from category then pass it to option subcategory with return value, return value can solve your question, example : onchange= "return.this.value" in your option category. 
This example maybe can help you : http://suckittrees.com/artikel-209/database-desa-kecamatan-kabupatenkota-dan-provinsi-se-indonesia--program-ajax.html